# Replace the first line with the longest java text file

Tags: java

i need to replace the first line in the text file with the longest and vice versa. Please tell me what i need to fix and add. At this stage the program looks for the longest line properly. I'm new to Java, I'm sure there is not much to fix, but I do not know what exactly is needed. Also, if possible, help implement the output of the result in a new file.
 The code still looks like this:

```
package pkg;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    static int previousLongLine = 0;

    public void printLongLine(HashMap longLineMap) {

        Set keyofSet = longLineMap.keySet();
        Iterator itr = keyofSet.iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            Integer keys = (Integer) itr.next();
            String value = (String) longLineMap.get(keys);
            System.out.println("Line Number of Longest line: " + keys
                    + "\nLongest line: " + value);
        }
    }
public static void main(String []args){
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String fileName = "G:\\colege\\bursa\\Colege\\Programing\\pkg\\File1.txt";
        // This will reference one line at a time
        String line = null;
        int key = 0;
        int lineSize = 0, lineNumber = 0;

        Main ln = new Main();

        HashMap longLineMap = new HashMap();

        try {
            // FileReader reads text files in the default encoding.
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);

            // Always wrap FileReader in BufferedReader.
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                lineNumber++;



                lineSize = line.length();
                if (lineSize > previousLongLine) {
                    previousLongLine = lineSize;
                    longLineMap.clear();
                    longLineMap.put(lineNumber, line);
                }



                if(lineNumber == 1){
                    String old = line;
                    String newl = old.replaceFirst(old, String.valueOf(previousLongLine));

                }
            }

            //close files.
            bufferedReader.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("Unable to open file '" + fileName + "'");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error reading file '" + fileName + "'");
        }

        ln.printLongLine(longLineMap);
    }
}
```

Comment: Edit your question with the code, don't post code in the comments.

Comment: I will insert the full code in response

Comment: It probably "knocks out an error", because you're not supposed to paste all your code in there, but instead provide a [mre].

Comment: I edited the post

Comment: Does the output want to overwrite the input file?

Comment: I want the result to be written to a newly created file, for example, file2.txt

Comment: See my solution, paste this code into the main method, assign your file paths to the correct variable, and using the resources provided try to understand what is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with a simple stream operation.

Info on stream: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html

I've used try-with-resource, which auto-closes the resource after processing has ceased.

Info on try-with-resource: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

1. Read file into an ArrayList
2. Create another List to hold the sorted elements.
3. Open a stream on the ArrayList which holds the input data.
4. Sort the lines into size order. Use Comparator.reverseOrder() for largest to smallest
5. Using a downstream collector store the output as a new list.
6. Write sorted list to file.

Reading file:

```
String inputFile = "files/longestLine.txt";
List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();

try(BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile))) {

    String line = bufferedReader.readLine();

    while(line != null){
        lines.add(line);
        line = bufferedReader.readLine();
    }

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Use a stream to sort the lines into size order.

```
List<String> sortedLines = lines.stream()
                .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Write to file:

```
String outputFile = "outputFile.txt";

try(BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile))) {

            for (String line: sortedLines) {

                bufferedWriter.write(line);
                bufferedWriter.newLine();
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Thank you very much))